# Cannot access value for CheckboxSelectMultiple using request.POST

Tags: django, forms, checkbox

I am designing a form which uses CheckboxSelectMultiple to let a user select toppings for a pizza.  Topping is its own class with just a 'name' attribute.

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="pizza")
    style = models.ForeignKey(PizzaStyle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_special = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    num_toppings = models.IntegerField()
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, default=0.00, decimal_places=2)

class PizzaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pizza
        exclude = ['menu', 'price']
        widgets = {
            'toppings': CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        }
        labels = {
            'num_toppings': 'Number of Toppings',
            'is_special': 'Gluten Free Dough'
        }
```

The form creates fine in views.py with the correct labels for each Topping.  However, when I pass the form data to another page (cart), I can only pass the number of the last checkbox selected in the form. (i.e. if pepperoni is selected and is the third checkbox in the list, then request.POST['toppings'] returns 3.

I'm trying to do something like this in views.py for cart such that I can generate a list of toppings:

```
toppings = ""
for topping in request.POST['toppings']:
     print(topping.label)
     toppings = ", ".join(topping)
```

I have tried some searching through the documentation but cannot seem to figure out my problem. Thank you!

Comment: do you have a str function which return self.name in topping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: If you want to get the numbers / ids of all your selected items in a CheckboxSelectMultiple you need to use the getlist method:

```
for topping in request.POST.getlist('toppings'):
```

This will return a list of numbers of your selected toppings.

Having said that and looking at your code this still probably will not produce the results you want. If you change your last code snippet with the code sugggested you will get an `AttributeError`:

`'str' object has no attribute 'label`'

Because your number (as str) does not have this attribute.

So why not use the form? In your view:

```
form = PizzaForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    for topping in form.cleaned_data['toppings']:
        print(topping.label)
```

`form.cleaned_data` is a `dict` of your posted results. `form.cleaned_data['toppings']` is a `querset` with your selected toppings. With these you can do anything you want.